# Call function after other functions in Dart

Tags: dart

How can we invoke methods like:

```
MyClass obj = new MyClass();
obj.fun1().fun2()....;
```

Just like alertDialog in Android.

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle().create().show();
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's basically the builder pattern, where your methods return `this`, but you can do that even prettier in Dart with [`Method cascades`](https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/effective-dart/design#avoid-returning-this-from-methods-just-to-enable-a-fluent-interface):

```dart
MyClass obj = new MyClass()
  ..fun1()
  ..fun2()
  ..fun3();
```